# Absurd rendering of Callback function by Chrome in Argument

Tags: javascript, function, callback

In the following callback function example when Chrome Interpreter parses Line 2 - Why does it say

```
callback = (i)
```

What does this mean? Callback is a function and it must have said:

```
callback = function(i) {console.log(i);}
```

Though, in end I get "12" printed, but I am unable to understand when callback function is passed as argument to doSomeStuff(), then why on interpretation the argument reads it to be only "i" and not the full function as it exists.

[image]

Comment: It gives me `function()`

Comment: I have given snapshot.

Comment: May be something specific with chrome version. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fbz8y7jk/)

Comment: Seems like it just means "A function that accepts a single parameter named `i`"